# Why do we write window.?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, window-object

While adding some initialisation code to a webpage, I found myself writing `window.onload = ...` for the umptieth time, when a thought hit me.

The `window.` isn't necessary, because `window` is the current object. So it's optional!
But nobody writes just `onload = ...` and I wonder why that is.

I mean, we have no qualms about writing other things, say `alert` without the `window.` qualifier.

```javascript
window.onload = function() {
  alert('Your window has loaded');
};
```

while in reality, `alert` is just as much a method of the `window` object as the `onload` is.
So, why the difference? Why do even formal websites like the [W3C](http://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/docs/UserManual.html) do this?

Comment: It's *explicit*, so nobody thinks you're just accidentally assigning to a global variable.

Comment: I like this argument, as it explains the difference. Assigning something to a variable vs calling a function - you couldn't possibly create a new function by just calling it, hence it's clear that the function already exists somewhere.

Comment: @Bergi Can you post this as an answer? I think this is still the most compelling argument.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We write `window.` when we want to be explicit about it. There are basically two cases when this is good form to use it:

- properties and methods of the `window` object - everything that is part of the [`Window` interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window). The `.onload` listener you've mentioned is an example of this, things like `window.scrollY`, `window.status`, `window.parent`, `window.open()`, `window.focus()`, `window.removeEventListener()` are others.
- creation of global properties. Assigning to `window.myGlobalVar` from any scope is a common JS idiom to create a global "variable". Admittedly, it is still better practise to explicitly declare it with `var`.

While we could "optionally" omit the `window.` part here, it's uncommon. Especially creation of [implicitly global variables](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) through assignment is despised, and usually seen as a mistake. So if you do it on purpose, you declare your intention by using `window.`.

However, the first case is not always well-defined. We often do omit the `window.` part when the property we want to use is essentially a static, global variable, and not necessarily related to the `window` object even when it is formally specified on it. You seldom see anybody using `document`, `atob()`, `Worker`, `setTimeout()` or `fetch()` with the `window.` prefix, just as you don't use `window.JSON.parse` or `window.Array` for the *built-in objects* (although it would be valid).

For some other properties like `navigator`, `location` or `alert()` it is not always clear, and those are used maybe fifty-fifty without or not.

Answer (score 5):

I see following reasons:

1. Reduce searching up the *scope-chain* will improve the performance *slightly*. This is also seen in the IIFE where `window` is sent as parameter to the function and inside it the local reference to the window is used.
2. If the function/member defined on `window` globally is overriden in the scope, then it'll not work as expected, so referencing explicitly makes it refer to the correct function/member. This is useful to create the function/member with the same name as the global one and still able to access the global member from shadowed scope.

Comment: OK, but why the difference? Why doesn't everybody write `window.alert` instead of `alert`, which would also improve performance?

Comment: @MrLister check `function onload() {
    // Code Here
}

onload = something;`, here `onload` will not work as expected. And as explained by Andre in the answer, `onload` is not only limited to `window`, it can be applied to `img`, `iframe`, etc. so it is explicitly added on window. In case of `alert` it is not that _critical_ function, even when it is overwrite it doesn't harm the code(as opposed to `onload`).

Answer (score 1):

Because `.onload` isn't exclusive to `window`. It can also be used, for example, as `document.onload`. So you define it depending on when you want your script to be executed.

Comment: OK, but why the difference? Why doesn't everybody write `window.alert` instead of `alert`, which also isn't exclusive?

Answer (score -2):

window object is by default initialized by browser. Its a good 
practice to defined  explicitly window object it effect on performance &your code will become understandable.